# Which vs what in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

We did not know about that, WHICH/WHAT caused us thinking in a wrong direction.

What is the correct form of this sentence?

Thanks

Comment: Please give more details about the sentence and maybe an example, because they are both words, but in what context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to use a relative pronoun. ***Which*** is generally accepted as a relative pronoun. Use of ***what*** as a relative pronoun is non-standard, though common in some dialects. If you are writing for anything even vaguely formal, you should use *which*.

There is room to discuss when to use *which* and when to use *what* when using them as interrogatives. Both of them have very similar use in that role. As relative pronouns, it is much clearer. Use *which*.